# Issues with strsplit only on Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, ubuntu-18.04, shiny-server

I am trying to perform a `strsplit` on a character vector to extract a date. It works like a charm in RStudio, but throws a `Error in strsplit: non-character argument` when deployed on an Ubuntu server with shiny.

### the data

The data I am working with is the Advisory Forecast Track of Hurricanes, provided by the [NOAA](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/archive_forecast_results.php?id=al02&year=2019&name=Hurricane%20BARRY). I load the data into R as a kml file, which becomes a SpatialPointsDataFrame. This df includes HTML-tables at points@data$Description that look like the following (in my example length = 5, when using the [NOAA-file `AL022019_018adv_TRACK.kmz`](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/storm_graphics/api/AL022019_018adv_TRACK.kmz)):

```
[1] <table>  <tr><td><font color=black><b>Tropical Depression Barry (AL022019)</b></font></td></tr>  <tr><td>Advisory #18</td></tr>  <tr><td><hr></td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Advisory Information</td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Valid at:  4:00 PM CDT July 14, 2019 </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Location: 32.8 N, -93.6 W </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Maximum Wind: 30 knots (35 mph) </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Wind Gusts: 40 knots (45 mph) </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Motion: N </td></tr> <tr><td nowrap>Minimum Pressure: 1008 mb </td></tr>

[2] <table>  <tr><td><font color=black><b>Tropical Depression Barry (AL022019)</b></font></td></tr>  <tr><td>Advisory #18</td></tr>  <tr><td><hr></td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>12 hr Forecast</td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Valid at:  1:00 AM CDT July 15, 2019 </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Location: 33.9 N, -93.6 W </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Maximum Wind: 25 knots (30 mph) </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Wind Gusts: 35 knots (40 mph) </td></tr>  <!-- HIDE_MOTION --> <!-- HIDE_PRES -->
```

### the code

The Code I'm using to extract the date from these table-vectors is the following:

```r
points <- rgdal::readOGR("al022019_018adv_TRACK.kml"), require_geomType = "wkbPoint")

    day <- strsplit(as.character(points$Description), "Valid at: ") %>%
      sapply(.,`[`,2) %>%
      strsplit(., ", 2019") %>%
      sapply(.,`[`,1) %>%
      strsplit(., "MDT | PDT | EDT | CDT ") %>%
      sapply(., `[`, 2) %>%
      strsplit(., " ") %>%
      sapply(., `[`, 2)
```

Interestingly, I can print a `class(as.character(points$Description))`-function right before the `strsplit` which results in `character`.

Is it something in the piping operation?

### the problem

When I run the code locally - whether in an R script or an shiny app, it runs smooth. The error occurs only when running the app on an Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS server:

```
Warning: Error in strsplit: non-character argument
  [No stack trace available]
```

What am I missing?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: May be itis the attributes of `points` causing thee issue.  Can you check the `class` of the column.  Also, try to print the `as.character(points$Description)`

Comment: When I print the vector it returns the data as shown above, as a character vector. When I run `class(as.character(points$Description))` it returns `character` as expected.

Comment: In that case, try only `strsplit(as.character(points$Description), "Valid at: ")` step and see if the error occur.  Also, better to use `traceback` or `debugonce`

Comment: You write that the tables are in `points@data$Description` but your script refers to them as  `points$Description`. Is it possible that the structure of your data is slightly different running the script locally?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. 
@TimTeaFan: the structure seems to be fine, even after uploading to the server.

Comment: @akrun: tried your debugging approach. The error seems to occur right after the first strsplit. But I'm gonna stop debugging here and move to @Andrew|s answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to extract the digits after the month (it looks like that is what your code is doing), then something like this *could* be more robust for Shiny. It is adaptable, but right now assumes that you always want the digit(s) after the full month name, and the the month will always need to be in title case.

```
library(stringr)

# Create pattern using a lookbehind to extract at least one digit
# following a capitalized month name with whitespace preceding it
pattern <- paste(paste0("(?<=", month.name, "\\s)\\d+"), collapse = "|")

# Extract digits (could use str-extract all for multiple matches)
stringr::str_extract(strings, pattern)
[1] "14" "15"
```

**Data**:

```
strings <- c("[<tr><td><font color=black><b>Tropical Depression Barry (AL022019)</b></font></td></tr>  <tr><td>Advisory #18</td></tr>  <tr><td><hr></td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Advisory Information</td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Valid at:  4:00 PM CDT July 14, 2019 </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Location: 32.8 N, -93.6 W </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Maximum Wind: 30 knots (35 mph) </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Wind Gusts: 40 knots (45 mph) </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Motion: N </td></tr> <tr><td nowrap>Minimum Pressure: 1008 mb </td></tr>",
             "<tr><td><font color=black><b>Tropical Depression Barry (AL022019)</b></font></td></tr>  <tr><td>Advisory #18</td></tr>  <tr><td><hr></td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>12 hr Forecast</td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Valid at:  1:00 AM CDT July 15, 2019 </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Location: 33.9 N, -93.6 W </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Maximum Wind: 25 knots (30 mph) </td></tr>  <tr><td nowrap>Wind Gusts: 35 knots (40 mph) </td></tr>  <!-- HIDE_MOTION --> <!-- HIDE_PRES -->   ")
```

Comment: That's a brilliant solution for my problem. I've loaded stringr already. Thanks a lot!